# Python ctypes argtypes for class object pointer

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

I have this `C++` code to integrate my class `Foo` based code into python.

```cpp
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){};
    int do_thing(int arg){ return arg*2; }
};

extern "C" {
Foo* get_foo_obj(){
    return new Foo;
}

int do_thing(Foo* ptr, int arg){
    return ptr->do_thing(arg);
}
}
```

Now I want to assign `argtypes` and `restype` for the functions from python.

```py
lib = ctypes.CDLL("mylib.so")
lib.get_foo_obj.restype = <POINTER?>
lib.do_thing.argtypes = (<POINTER?>, c_int)
lib.do_thing.restype = c_int
```

What would be the correct `ctypes` I need to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes.c_void_p` works (`void*` in C), although you can be more type safe with an opaque pointer type like:

```
import ctypes as ct

class Foo(ct.Structure):
    pass

lib = ct.CDLL('mylib.so')
lib.get_foo_obj.argtypes = ()
lib.get_foo_obj.restype = ct.POINTER(Foo)
lib.do_thing.argtypes = ct.POINTER(Foo), ct.c_int
lib.do_thing.restype = ct.c_int

foo = lib.get_foo_obj()
print(lib.do_thing(foo, 5))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! You have to make sure you assign the `restype` of the `get_foo_obj` function. Otherwise, the returned object pointer becomes an int inside python.