# Calling plain-C functions with "opaque pointer"

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries

I have a problem (I think) similar to what discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440067/python-ctypes-argtypes-for-class-object-pointer):

I need to call functions contained in a rather complex plain-C shared lib:

- all functions return an `int` acting as error code (as usual `0` means "all green").
- first call ever returns (in argument) an opaque pointer to an "instance".
- this pointer must be passed to all further function invocations.

In plain-C this translates to something like:

```c
lib_instance *instance;
static lib_ConfigParameters configParams;
static const void* descriptorTable[] = { ... };

int main() {
    int32_t ret;
    ret = lib_getDefaultParams(&configParams);
    // check ret
    configParams.whatever = someParam;
    ret = lib_init(&instance, &configParams, descriptorTable, sizeof(descriptorTable)/sizeof(descriptorTable[0]);
    // check ret
    ret = lib_somefunc(&instance, someparam);
    ...
}
```

I tried something along the lines:

```py
from ctypes import cdll, Structure, CDLL, POINTER, c_int

class Params(Structure):
    pass

lib = CDLL('../Lib/lib.so')
lib.lib_getParamDefaults.argtypes = (POINTER(Params),)
lib.lib_getParamDefaults.restype = c_int
par = Params()
ret = lib.lib_getParamDefaults(par)
print(ret, par)
```

but already at this level `par` does not seem to contain anything useful.

I also have no idea how to handle the "instance" stuff.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Of course `par` doesn't contain anything useful, it has no contents!  It needs a `_fields_` member, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions).

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks, understood, but two questions pop up: 1) is there any way to generate definitions from C headers? 2) (actually the original OP question) how do i deal with "opaque" pointers? (i.e.: `configParams` vs. `instance`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.  First of all, you need a variable that can hold your opaque pointer.  Second, you need to pass a *pointer* to that variable into the C function.  A structure might be able to hold the opaque pointer if you defined it properly, but it seems like an over-complicated solution. There's a [`c_void_p` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) that seems ideally suited.

I haven't tested this code but I think it does what you want.

```
from ctypes import cdll, CDLL, c_int, c_void_p, byref

lib = CDLL('../Lib/lib.so')
# ...
par = c_void_p()
ret = lib.lib_getParamDefaults(byref(par))
print(ret, par)
```